# No GUI for Wine on 18.04 Budgie

Tags: wine, 18.04, budgie

It installs fine but there is no GUI anywhere for it nor is it in the recommended open with programs. I'm guessing its a repository issue because in the software updater I get this error.

```
E:The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file. 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file. 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
W:GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: 
 The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 
E:The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com precise Release' is not signed.
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists/1039279#1039279) while waiting the provider to release Bionic version of Wine. If it installs fine, I assume you're using the *universe* version of the Wine instead of WineHQ's.

Comment: This worked thank you. But I dont know what to check your response. As a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

After installing `wine` (assuming you're successfully installed it), you need to generate the config file by simply running `winecfg` after installation. It will generate 64-bit `WINEPREFIX`, so if you need the 32-bit `WINEPREFIX`, you need to pass the argument `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=path_to_wineprefix` before running `winecfg`. (see [WineHQ FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ) for more information)

If you need something which has more GUI for your configuration, [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) is your solution. However, there is no Bionic release for POL, yet. You need to manually configure the mirror and use Xenial release, which I doubt it won't conflict with the main Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Just going from bionic to artful did the trick